# Need a Suggestion on Sharepoint project Architecture

Tags: development, architecture

Actually we need to develop an intranet portal for a company. There will be a common landing page and each department will have their own subsite which will be driven through a navigation from the common landing page.

data will be parked in the list and some list will be available to all and some will be department specific.

I got this project in a stage where  team have used SP UI+ SPD and designed the lists.Basically no content type and they have hard coded the values for some of the columns. (Ex: Choice Columns)

Customer has not provided any branding so they created a team site and created all the list there.

When I looked it and laid out the following design:

I thought we can design a blank site and create a master page. Have few configuration list defined and groups. Save this site as a template and import it into VS to extend it further.

Basically this will act as a main site and can be resued to create the subsite for each departments.

But I am not sure how I can leverage their existing Lists which they have already created on a common site and how should I add it to VS project. Basically my goal is to create one VS project so that we get one wsp ( or multiple) while deploying it.
How can I reuse the existing lists for the VS?
Can you please review it and suggest any approch.

Thanks

Ank